# Additional restrictions on starting activities from the background with MODE_BACKGROUND_ACTIVITY_START_ALLOWED

Tags: android, android-14

In the decument
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#background-activity-restrictions

you can see that.

> For apps targeting Android 14, the system further restricts when apps
> are allowed to start activities from the background:
>
> When an app sends a PendingIntent using PendingIntent#send() or
> similar methods, the app must now opt in if it wants to grant its own
> background activity launch privileges to start the pending intent. To
> opt in, the app should pass an ActivityOptions bundle with
> setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityStartMode(MODE_BACKGROUND_ACTIVITY_START_ALLOWED).

So i tried that case with service like this.

```
class TimeChangeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED ||
        intent.action == Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED ||
        intent.action == Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK ||
        intent.action == "android.intent.action.TIME_SET"
        ) {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(context, TimeChangeService::class.java)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent)
        } else {
            context.startService(serviceIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class TimeChangeService : Service() {
private var timeChangeReceiver: TimeChangeReceiver? = null
val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel"
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    timeChangeReceiver = TimeChangeReceiver()
}

@RequiresApi(34)
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val noti = createNotification()
    //use notification foreground service 
    startForeground(1, noti.build())
     val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE, options.toBundle()).

        // use send function
        pendingIntent.send()

    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    timeChangeReceiver?.let {
        unregisterReceiver(it)
    }
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

private fun createNotification(): NotificationCompat.Builder {
    val channelId = "my_channel_id"
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "My Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

  
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
        .setContentText("Foreground Service is running")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    return notification
}
```

}

if user change time or date, broadcastReceiver get action and start serivce.

in service,there is start activity with pendingIntent and i think that case is start activity from background
but when i change the date, pendingIntent.send() not work no error code either( related with  MODE_BACKGROUND_ACTIVITY_START_ALLOWED)

can you explain how can  i make sample case properly?